# Pic32 Real Time Self Programming

Tags: flash, memory, rtsp, pic32

Good evening, 
I'm new with PIC family and I need to implement the RTSP on my bootloader.

I read several pdf's about this topic but I can't get any example code on how to write on FPM.
[The data to be written in flash are sent through the CAN-BUS]

Can you help me providing any example code in c code for mplab or document that explains this topic?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "RTSP".

There are basically 2 ways, one is having a bootloader that you activate and will get your can messages and write the flash on the specific memory regions.

The second way, that only works with the dual flash chips, is that you can can have your application written up in one of the section and you can write on the other section "Dual Flash". Then you can select which section to use at boot-up and this doesn't require bootloader.

There are plenty of example on the Harmony framework.